# Display raw buffer as an image directly in the chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a raw buffer from the api call. When I run it in a browser it is just downloading one raw file. I want to display the image directly in the browser but it is not working . Can you please guide me?

```
var optionsPhoto = {
        url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/photo/$value",
        encoding: null, 
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
      };
    await request(optionsPhoto, function callback(error, response, body) 
    {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
                res.send(body)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a buffer in image tag `src` ?

Answer (score -1):

U can use a blob to encapsulate received data and createObjectURL

```
let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array([...yourBuffer]).buffer]);

//createObjectURL && asign it to ur image src
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```